# Should I add users to a role or add a role to a user in .Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a screen that lists users. It doesn't show what roles they have. I have another screen that lists users for a particular role that I select from a drop down.

What I am trying to decide is. Should I have an [add role] button on the user screen or [add user button on the role screen. It would seem to me that either would be okay but before starting a couple hours of coding I would like to find out if anyone has any suggestions on the best way to do this.

Hope this question is allowed. I really would like to find out if there is an advantage or disadvantage with one or other choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you add users to roles - Permissions are generally granted to roles not users, so if you're trying to fnid out who has access to [Blah] you'll usually want a list of all users with a specified role.

That's not to say you shouldn't offer additional information on users to list roles - perhaps in a popup or similar

Answer (score 0):

That is depending on how your users usually use your application. Make a user study and find out.

Probably the most common use case is to create a new user and add roles to that user.
The use case of creating a new role and assigning a bunch of users is less common in most systems. But yours may differ?

One solution is of course to implement both.